# CCLayerColor Problems

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a CCLayerColor:

```
 "NameLayer" = [CCLayerColor layerWithColor: (ccc4 (125.125,
225.225))width: height 118.0f, 118.0f];
```

where initialize another class:

```
"nameColor" = [[NameLayer alloc] init];
```

Now I'm trying to make a method to change the size of my CCLayerColor but I do not get it.

I'm using:

```
[nameColor setContentSize: size],
```

but it seems to me that I change the size of "inside" of the layer and not the length. I hope I have explained to me the problem well.

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use change[- (void) changeWidth:(GLfloat)w height:(GLfloat)h](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.5/interface_c_c_layer_color.html#a962603ad032b623af5408c2f0c0c8e8e) not setContentSize. But why ?

- The method setContentSize will set the size of the content of the layer not the size of the layer, like you told : `it seems to me that I change the size of "inside" of the layer and not the length.`
- The method changeWidth: height: will set the width and the height of the layer, and not the  content of the layer!

Hope it help you!

Comment: It was more or less what I was thinking to do.

I create the method `-(void)changeWidth:(GLfloat)w height:(GLfloat)h` inside the method I try to change but I do not get it, should not be doing well the code. He needed a few more tips, I think I lack a something in between.

Greetings

Comment: You need to do something like: [nameColor changeWidth:50 height:50];

Comment: Just let me do: [self changeWidth: 50 height: 50]; , can not do: [nameColor changeWidth: 50 height: 50];. I do not understand why.